# How do i get the value of an item in tkinter when using a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted to learn a bit of tkinter. I followed a couple guides by [sentdex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ccct5D2AyNM&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe8XSftW-RAxdo6OmaeL85M&index=40) on Youtube and feel like I have a good understanding of the basics. However, now I am trying to write a script that works as quick log and I am running into issues getting the text from the entry/text/optionmenu.

If I set up the gui outside of class I can simply do a variable.get() and all is ducky. But when I have my gui tkinter stuff in a class I get an Exception that  is not defined.

Here is my code. The issue lies in def saveButtonCommand(self):

How do I get the values of noteText and officeOption/Var?

```
# Imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys, datetime

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("SPL - " + str(datetime.date.today()))
        self.configure(background="#e7e7e7")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # Menu -> Quit, Open Log

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Open Log")
        file.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

        # Window Items

        # Office Drop Down
        OFFICES = [
            "County Building",
            "Adult Probation",
            "Building & Zoning",
            "Circuit Court",
            "    - CC. Family Division",
            "    - CC. Friend of the Court",
            "    - CC. Juvenile Division",
            "Clerk",
            "Commissioners",
            "Computer Infomration Systems",
            "Corporation Counsel",
            "District Court",
            "    - DC. Community Corrections",
            "    - DC. Magistrate Office",
            "    - DC. Probation Office",
            "Economic Development Corp.",
            "Equalization",
            "Maintenance",
            "Probate Court",
            "Prosecuting Attorney",
            "Public Guardian",
            "Register of Deeds",
            "Sheriff Department",
            "    - SD. Booking",
            "    - SD. Kitchen",
            "    - SD. Records",
            "    - SD. Squadroom",
            "Social Security",
            "Tax Mapping/GIS",
            "Treasurer",
            "Veteran's"
        ]

        officeLabel = Label(self, text="Office:", fg="#000000", bg="#e7e7e7", font="Verdana 10")
        officeLabel.place(x=5,y=5)

        officeOptionVar = StringVar()
        officeOptionVar.set(OFFICES[0]) # Default Value

        officeOption = OptionMenu(self, officeOptionVar, *OFFICES)
        officeOption.place(x=5,y=28,width=310)

        # Note
        noteLabel = Label(self, text="Note:", fg="#000000", bg="#e7e7e7", font="Verdana 10")
        noteLabel.place(x=5,y=58)

        noteText = Text()
        noteText.place(x=5, y=81, width=310, height=225)

        # Save Button
        saveButton = Button(self, text='Save', command=self.saveButtonCommand)
        saveButton.place(x=5, y=312, width=310, height=50)

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def saveButtonCommand(self):
        office = officeOptionVar.get()
        note = noteText.get("1.0","end-1c")
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Test", message=note)

root = Tk()
root.resizable(0,0)

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

geo_width = 320
geo_height = 370
geo_offset_w = int((screen_width/2)-(geo_width/2))

root.geometry(str(geo_width) + "x" + str(geo_height) + "+" + str(geo_offset_w) + "+200")


app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I fixed it, you should use self."variable-name" to declare an accessible attribute.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys, datetime

class Window(Frame):

def __init__(self, master = None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master
    self.init_window()

def init_window(self):
    self.master.title("SPL - " + str(datetime.date.today()))
    self.configure(background="#e7e7e7")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    # Menu -> Quit, Open Log

    menu = Menu(self.master)
    self.master.config(menu=menu)

    file = Menu(menu)
    file.add_command(label="Open Log")
    file.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.client_exit)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

    # Window Items

    # Office Drop Down
    OFFICES = [
        "County Building",
        "Adult Probation",
        "Building & Zoning",
        "Circuit Court",
        "    - CC. Family Division",
        "    - CC. Friend of the Court",
        "    - CC. Juvenile Division",
        "Clerk",
        "Commissioners",
        "Computer Infomration Systems",
        "Corporation Counsel",
        "District Court",
        "    - DC. Community Corrections",
        "    - DC. Magistrate Office",
        "    - DC. Probation Office",
        "Economic Development Corp.",
        "Equalization",
        "Maintenance",
        "Probate Court",
        "Prosecuting Attorney",
        "Public Guardian",
        "Register of Deeds",
        "Sheriff Department",
        "    - SD. Booking",
        "    - SD. Kitchen",
        "    - SD. Records",
        "    - SD. Squadroom",
        "Social Security",
        "Tax Mapping/GIS",
        "Treasurer",
        "Veteran's"
    ]

    officeLabel = Label(self, text="Office:", fg="#000000", bg="#e7e7e7", font="Verdana 10")
    officeLabel.place(x=5,y=5)

    self.officeOptionVar = StringVar()
    self.officeOptionVar.set(OFFICES[0]) # Default Value

    officeOption = OptionMenu(self, self.officeOptionVar, *OFFICES)
    officeOption.place(x=5,y=28,width=310)

    # Note
    noteLabel = Label(self, text="Note:", fg="#000000", bg="#e7e7e7",      font="Verdana 10")
    noteLabel.place(x=5,y=58)

    self.noteText = Text()
    self.noteText.place(x=5, y=81, width=310, height=225)

    # Save Button
    saveButton = Button(self, text='Save', command=self.saveButtonCommand)
    saveButton.place(x=5, y=312, width=310, height=50)

def client_exit(self):
    exit()

def saveButtonCommand(self):
    office = self.officeOptionVar.get()
    note = self.noteText.get("1.0","end-1c")
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Test", message=note)

 root = Tk()
 root.resizable(0,0)

 screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
 screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

 geo_width = 320
 geo_height = 370
 geo_offset_w = int((screen_width/2)-(geo_width/2))

 root.geometry(str(geo_width) + "x" + str(geo_height) + "+" + str(geo_offset_w) + "+200")


 app = Window(root)
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried every combination of adding self to the saveButtonCommand function I didn't think to add it to the variables themselves. Forest through the trees.